# Massive logging on heroku with socket.io

Tags: logging, heroku, socket.io

I am using socket.io on heroku.  To do this I have to use [xhr-polling on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).  However, this makes it so there is massive amounts of logs being created.

`2013-04-25T20:15:49.255467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/cOO67jH_mH2cIjDt5OWX?t=1372192165157 host=xyz.com fwd="123.12.12.123" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2044ms status=200 bytes=3`

I tried reducing the amount of logging that socket io does by using

```
io.configure ()-> 
    io.set "transports", ["xhr-polling"]
```

But it looks like the logging might be at the heroku level as opposed to the socket.io level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the logging level. Look for 'log level'... https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO